# Which of my items should I take on missions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I find a lot of junk that I want to sell to make money.  Some things I can take with me when I explore, but my carrying capacity is limited.  Should I only take what I need from an area, with the hope that later I can return to that place and pick things up to sell?

The biggest problem for me is that its hard to know what people will buy and if I don't have at least a sample I won't know how good the buyer is.

Comment: i try not to cheat, so I don't want to look up on internet where the best buyers are.

Comment: When you say "best buyer", do you mean they buy the widest range of goods, or they give you the best price for your goods?

Comment: are you asking about what you should take IN to a dungeon or OUT of a dungeon?

Comment: @Arkive that is a good question, nowadays I sell to whoever wants to buy.

Comment: @yx. I ask what to take after I leave my home and go to a dungeon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I like to do is when you get the first house, the storage is (seeminly) infinite in the chests, so I have chests categorized by item type (useless, smithing/chanting, alchemy, etc) and when my carry is getting too high, I empty my stocks into their respective places, and every once in a while I sell, smith, enchant, etc. to get rid of all the stuff I don't use.

On any outings, I carry weapons, armor, arrows (they require no weight) along with proper potions (I don't need to have a potion to improve smithing while dungeoneering).

While looting I typically pickup anything with a decent value (at least 100+) and then I just drop generic weapons (I don't need to sell 50 Ancient Nordic swords).  I tend to keep any profession material + weapons with enchants + high value items.

I'm more of a warrior spec so even with heavy armor + shield + a spare weapon for the occasional DW and a proper bow (though, I just moved on to Bound Bow) and I have usually around 200 extra carry weight to use for whatever I pickup.

It all comes back to play style in the end but generally assume most things have some value but keep in mind the things you can drop for other, more worthwhile items.

There is a perk once you get high enough speech craft that will allow you to sell anything to anyone no matter what kind of store it is and a separate perk to allow you to sell stolen items as well.

Answer (score 12):

### Here are a few tips for you:

- **Get a safe storage place**. Keep all the junk that you won't need for sure and are sure you are going to sell inside the storage, and come back from time to time to get sell off some of said junk. To do that you need to get a house, or join a guild/organization.
- **Keep some spare room**. I always make sure to keep about 30%-50% of my carry capacity available in order to have the ability to collect all the junk that I want along the way.
- **Increase your carry capacity**. If you see that you do not have enough room on you simply allow yourself to carry more. To do that you need to increase your Stamina when you get new levels.
- **Get the "Merchant" perk**. I would say it's the most useful perk I ever got, it allows you to sell any kind of item to any kind of trader. You won't have to worry about who accepts what items any more.
- **Get the "Extra Pockets" perk**. It increases your carrying capacity by 100. (Thanks to Crag for the suggestion)

Comment: The "Merchant" perk is a great suggestion, but you didn't mention the "Extra Pockets" perk that increases your carrying capacity by 100!

Comment: Merchant perk isn't that useful if you have unlocked a certain group of merchants who are willing to buy everything (can't mention more than that since he doesn't want spoilers).

Comment: @yx. When you've got 10s of thousands of gold worth of stuff to sell, those speech perks come in handy with or without that group of merchants -- being able to sell to every merchant in a city means way less time spent fast traveling.

Comment: @yx, I did unlock em, but being able to sell any of my crap at any shop in any town is still kinda useful.

Comment: Also check the merchants regularly to find the Carrying Capacity enchant. The first one I found between level 25-30 was "Scaled Boots of Brawn" with +40 Carrying Capacity.

Comment: The Steed Stone is also great... gives +100 carry and your armor isn't included in your total weight

Comment: Also, don't forget the Thieves Guild Armor that increases your carrying capacity by 20!

Answer (score 1):

Take a companion with you wherever you go. Now they **do** have a carrying capacity **if** you directly trade with them; however, if you aim your crosshair at them from a short distance and hold action, the crosshair will spin and begin to pulse. This allows you to give orders from a distance: Move here, stay there, kill that and the most useful of all, **pick that up**! If you do it this way your companions have an unlimited storage capacity. They won't search corpses or open chests so the best way is to pick up the items then drop them on the floor then order them to pick them up.

I disagree with the above post, I wouldn't take any perks in speech as it's a waste of points. Do the thieves guild quests and you will unlock people that you can fence your unwanted items too (including stolen items). One of these guys will carry up to 4k in gold for buying your items. If you want better prices and better all around skills, invest in enchanting and alchemy. You can enchant items to give you higher speech and better pricing plus with Alchemy you can create barter potions that you can drink before each purchase or sale of items.

A tip for leveling speech - sell one item at a time. If you sell them all at once it does not count towards the speech skill only the first item sold does. So yes it takes forever but you increase your speech skill = better prices as it increases.